# Cocoa Pods: Local Pod install issue

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I am trying to install a library through local podspec. This is how my podspec looks like

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name = 'MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT'
s.version = '1.0.0'
s.license = { :type => 'Unspecified' }
s.homepage = 'https://www.modirum.com'
s.authors = { 'Modirum Ou' => 'info@modirum.com' }
s.summary = 'Modirum 3DS SDK iOS framework (Development)'
s.platform = :ios
s.source = { :path => './LocalPods/MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT.framework.zip' }
s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT.framework'
end
```

when I run the `pod install` pods installed successfully but it does not copy the `'MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT.framework'` in the XCode project. So I am having the following error

[image]

So don't know is there something wrong with the Pod itself or I am missing something in the installation. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:
Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'ModirumSDKExample' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ModirumSDKExample
  pod 'MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT', :path => './LocalPods/MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT.podspec'

end
```

Comment: Can you paste your project Podfile? Also, is there a specific need to use a .zip framework?

Comment: Thanks @alxlives for responding. SDK docs say to use the .zip framework. I don't know which is the best way to use either .zip of .framework itself.

Comment: # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'ModirumSDKExample' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ModirumSDKExample
  pod 'MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT', :path => './LocalPods/MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT.podspec'

end

Comment: Could you confirm that your `MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT.podspec` is at the same place as `MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT.framework` in folder hierarchy?

Comment: @Larme yes, I confirm that both MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT.podspec and MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT.framework.zip are in same folder.

Comment: Just to double check, are you using the `.xcworkspace` file to open the project? Can you see the Development Pods folder?

Comment: @alxlives yes, I am using the `.xcworkspace` file and it has the Pods folder. Only way working for me not using the .zip framework instead I extract it to .framework and then it brings the framework correctly in the XCode project and it builds file. So not sure if .zip framework actually working with Cocoapods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Cocoapods Documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods-core/1.7.5/Pod/Specification/DSL#source=-instance_method), it seems that .zip files are only unarchivable via http resources:

> Using HTTP to download a compressed file of the code. It supports zip, tgz, bz2, txz and tar.

So this would work:

```
s.source = { :http => 'https://example.com/MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT.framework.zip' }
```

This would not:

```
s.source = { :path => './LocalPods/MI_SDK_DEVELOPMENT.framework.zip' }
```

Comment: Thanks @alxlives for pointing to right direction. So it means that we cannot use the local .zip framework through Cocoapods I have to put it to some remote location.